# Sync two git repositories Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to syncronize two repositories each time a build is been made, I have seen this script but I don't know how to set the remote branch with credentials too.

```
# clone the reposotory
git clone --bare $ORIGIN_URL

# add a remote repository
cd $REPO_NAME
git remote add --mirror=fetch repo1 $REPO1_URL

# update the local copy from the first repository
git fetch origin --tags

# update the local copy with the second repository
git fetch repo1 --tags

# sync back the 2 repositories
git push origin --all
git push origin --tags
git push repo1 --all
git push repo1 --tags
```

Pipeline:

```
node('centos-small') {
    sh 'git config --global user.email "jenkins@xxx.com"'
    sh 'git config --global user.name "ci-bot"'
    git credentialsId: 'JenkinsGit', url: 'git url'
}
```

I don't know how to set the credentials to push changes to remote repo.
git push repo1 --all
git push repo1 --tags

Comment: Have you ever solved it?

Comment: Hi, try the below solution, I don't know if it's the best way to do it but if you add :
sh 'git config --global credential.helper cache'
sh "git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'"
te credentials are maintained and then you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be triggered when something is pushed to the first repo (via webhook or similar)

```
node('centos-small') {
    stage('Set Git Config'){
        sh 'git config --global user.email "test@test.com"'
        sh 'git config --global user.name "ci-bot"'
        sh 'git config --global credential.helper cache'
        sh "git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'"
    }
    stage('Set Git Credentials'){
        git credentialsId: 'JenkinsGit', url: '${TFS_REPO}'
        git credentialsId: 'Second', url: '${SECOND_REPO}'
    }

    stage('Syncronize TFS-SECOND'){
        sh 'git clone --bare ${TFS_REPO} tfs'
        dir("tfs") {
            //add a remote repository
            sh 'git remote add --mirror=fetch second ${SECOND_REPO}'
            // update the local copy from the first repository
            sh 'git fetch origin --tags'

            // update the local copy with the second repository
            sh 'git fetch second --tags'

            // sync back the second repository
            sh 'git push second --all'
            sh 'git push second --tags'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there no plugin that would support these commands?